# comparing 2 objects and returning true if they ok using operator

Tags: c++, comparison, operator-keyword

I'm trying to compare 2 objects and return true if they match using operators with no luck. Please help with this code. I've tried using p.date extra but it didn't work

class name is `DateC`

```
bool DateC::operator-=(const DateC& p) const
{
    // if() {return true;};
    // return true;
};
assert( d -= DateC(1, 2, 2001) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want the `-=` operator, a lead would be :

```
const DateC & DateC::operator -=  ( const DateC& rhs) {

    this->day = ?;     // do something with rhs.day
    this->month = ?;   // do something with rhs.month 
    this->year = ?;    // do something with rhs.year 

    return *this;
}
```

But according to the title of your question, you are looking for `==` operator :

Another lead :

```
bool DateC::operator == ( const DateC &rhs ) const {

    if ((this->day != rhs.day) || 
        (this->month != rhs.month) || 
        (this->year != rhs.year))  {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use it as follows :

```
bool ok = (DateC(1,2,2001) == DateC(11,2,2001));      // Returns false
```

**Note :** Of course, you can replace my `==` by `-=`, but this would be kind of twisted, for anyone who wants to use it.

Comment: sorry that wont do the job , I just want to compare the object p to datec() if both are equal then return true. all inside the implementation I provided

Comment: I really don't get it. You want to compare two dates. like : `bool ok = (DateC(1,2,2001) == DateC(11,2,2001))`. That's what my second proposition is made for (`rhs` being your `p`)... Give it a try and see by yourself (or don't use operators).